# Bluetooth sound issue Quality since 22.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 22.04

since my update to Ubuntu 22.04 (no issues before that) the sound on my bluetooth headphones gets interrupted by electronic sounding disturbances (connecting the devices is no problem, A2DP works). They seem to be connected to the laptop downloading since they occur especially when I open websites or download updates (and not while installing). 
I don't know where to start and I'm thankful for any hints and ideas.
Thanks

System: 
Ubuntu 22.04 lts,
Lenovo X1 Carbon
Headphones: Sony WH-1000XM3

**Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb**
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0130]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS7500 Touch Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b531 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1199:9079 Sierra Wireless, Inc. EM7455
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.